# If you .Remove() a specific item from a List<T> does it also remove the 'empty slot'?

Tags: c#

Feel free to correct my terminology, and understanding of the List if needed..

If I have a list of five items where each item has a unique ID...

```
[item 1]
[item 2]
[item 3]
[item 4]
[item 5]
```

and I remove item with ID 72 (for example) and it happens to be 3rd in the List...

will it end up like this...

```
[item 1]
[item 2]
[null]
[item 4]
[item 5]
```

or like this

```
[item 1]
[item 2]
[item 3]
[item 4]
```

where what used to be item 4 is now item 3, etc.

Please explain if you can :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example

```
[item 1]
[item 2]
[item 3]
[item 4]
[item 5]
```

if you remove [item 3], then the List-class will just copy the part of the array 'behind' that item to the items index, the internal array of the list will look like this:

```
[item 1]
[item 2]
[item 4]
[item 5]
[default(item)]
```

You can't access the now last item however, since the List keeps a size variable to keep track of the number of its items which can be accessed. So practically, the List looks like your second example from the outside, but the internal array can actually be bigger.

**Edit:**
Also note that in reallity the array is much bigger than that, since the List<> will resize it when inserting items (it will double the array size when there's not enough room for the new item). For example, if you add 5 items to a list, then your list will already look like this:

```
[item 1]
[item 2]
[item 3]
[item 4]
[item 5]
[default(item)]
[default(item)]
[default(item)]
```

Comment: excellent, so again regardless of what I should care about I'm curious as to if this means that my List can potentially never really shrink, only grow, as if I remove things it stays the same size deep down, right?

Comment: The size will not decrease unless you call `TrimExcess()` or set the `Capacity` property.  The `List<T>` implementation does trim the array at any point unless you explicitly request it to.

Answer (score 15):

Second option. It behaves as a [List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_%28computing%29), not as an array.

> It is possible to remove an element at a particular index. The indices of previous elements at that and higher indices are decreased by 1.

Comment: It's also useful to note that because of this behavior, modification of a list's contents may not be made in a foreach iteration because the conditions of the foreach may not be altered.

Comment: When using a List<T> the 'empty slot' does NOT get removed. The elements are shiftet via Array.Copy, and the now invalid last 'empty slot' is filled with default(T).

Comment: @dkson and the new 'empty slot' will be at the very end of the List?

Comment: @Shogun: yes, but you can't 'see' or access it from the outside, since the List-class has a private member called _size. This member keeps the number of items in the list, but it is independent from the size of the array which is used inside the list to actually store the items. See my answer below.

Comment: @dkson so does that mean if I'm removing it this way it's not actually freeing up the resources? Like I am building up a bunch of 'empty slots'?

Comment: @Shogun This is nothing you should usually worry about, since the List<> is already full of those 'empty slots'. See my answer updated below.

Comment: @dkson: If you only care about the List interface, then it doesn't matter how it is implemented. The empty slot internally is an implementation detail. In F#, for example, Lists implemented by using a linked list structure. No empty slot there, but still having a List interface.

Comment: @codekaizen You're right of cause, but Shogun asked especially about the List<T> in C#. It is always good to know how things work under the hood, even if it matters only in some corner cases.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, with the implementation of `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`, the underlying array that is used to store items will end up like this:

```
[item 1]
[item 2]
[item 4]
[item 5]
[null]
```

That is, without changing the size of the array, the 3rd item has been removed and the 4th and 5th items have been shifted.

Of course if you enumerate the collection the trailing nulls are omitted because the size of the collection is used to determine where to stop.  (Edit: And attempts to access indicies beyond the logical end of the collection will fail.)

Comment: That's not 100% correct. If T is a value type, then the last item in the List's array is not null, but the default value of that value type.

Answer (score 1):

My statement has been corrected with technical observations, but for enumerable purposes, a List object, when you remove an item it is gone, like your second example.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx)